# Other forms does not work after redirect from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

So, I'm currently trying to learn some JSP, and I can't figure out how to get around this problem I'm having.

Currently, I have an index.jsp page with several forms. For one form, it has two text fields that it sends to a servlet, test.java, in order to build a string. After building the string, the servlet then redirects back to index.jsp

Original index.jsp address: 
     `http://localhost:8080/TestJSPConversion/`

After the redirect, the address is 
     `http://localhost:8080/TestJSPConversion/test`

The problem comes up when I try to use another form on index.jsp, it then takes me to a blank page at the address, 
     `http://localhost:8080/TestJSPConversion/test?author=Peter+Johnson`

I believe it's due to the method I'm using to redirect from the servlet (request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
but, I'm not too sure how to fix this issue. I would like to get the form to work even after the servlet redirects back to index.jsp.

Servlet Code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Get parameters from the request.
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    String message = null;
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    if (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM) {
        message = "Good Morning, ";
    } else {
        message = "Good Afternoon, ";
    }
    message += name + " with the email, " + email;

    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Index.jsp Code:

```
<h2>Choose authors:</h2>
<form method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Tan Ah Teck">Tan
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Mohd Ali">Ali 
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Kumar">Kumar 
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Peter Johnson">Peter
    <input type="submit" value="Query">
</form>

<c:set var="authorName" value="${param.author}" />
</br>
<c:if test="${not empty authorName}">
    <c:out value="${authorName}" />
</c:if>
</br>
<form  action="test" method="POST">  
    First Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br />  
    Surname: <input type="text" name="email" size="20">  
    <br /><br />  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
<c:out value="${message}" />
```

Comment: when you submit other form , do they have action="someServlet" where someServlet is an existing servlet ??

Comment: The other form just grabs the author name from the checkboxes and displays it, so it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : you only implement the doPost so your first Form with method=Get will prob. fail.

Second : you should use sendRedirect instead of forward.  this way if yo hit refresh on the browser, you will not get the warning about reposting data!  Always better to sendRedirect when the server process is done and you want to display the result in a JSP.

regards

Answer (score 1):

try `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?message=hello");` and display it using `${param.message}` (EL). If you are using method as post in `<form  action="test" method="POST">`, then you have to write the code in the `doPost` method.

Comment: Visruth, you are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

set action="test" for other `<form>` also.

if this leads you to some url like domain/TestJspConnection/test/test... then try action="/TestJSPConnection/test" as your `<form>` attribute

Oh yes, didn't notice this at all!...You didn't implement doGet() in your sevlet...so `<form method="get" >` is landing you on blank page

so..two solutions:

1) implement doGet() in servlet 
or 
 
2) set `method="post"` for first form

Comment: Implementing this still leads me to a blank page though. For example, clicking on Kumar gives me the address                         http://localhost:8080/TestJSPConversion/test?author=Kumar